# Steady solution for flow in Boussineq approximation in star

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, rotational-dynamics, astrophysics, stellar-physics

I am trying desperately to find the solution indicated in this question :

[image]

If I compute the equations on the 3 axis, I can't get the flow to be directed along $\vec{e_y}$

I have only :

$$\dfrac{\partial v_{z}}{\partial t} = -\dfrac{1}{\rho_0}\dfrac{\partial \delta P}{\partial z}+\alpha g \delta T\quad(1)$$

$$\dfrac{\partial v_{x}}{\partial t} - 2\Omega_{z} v_{y}=0\quad(2)$$

$$\dfrac{\partial v_{y}}{\partial t} + 2\Omega_{z} v_{x}=0\quad(3)$$

Anyone could see how to prove a flow directed along $\vec{e_{y}}$ for the steady solution of this equation ?

and with a gradient along $\vec{e_{z}}$ ?

Any help would be kind.

Comment: why have you taken $\nabla \delta P$ to be zero in the $x$ and $y$ directions?

Comment: -@PapaZulu since pression gradient is only radial, isn't it ? Have you got a solution ?

Comment: By radial do you mean $z$ direction? if not, a radial component will have $x$, $y$ and $z$ components. Also consider that the problem is steady ($\partial/\partial t = 0$). Is the flow incompressible? If so the continuity equation may be useful.

Comment: -@PapaZulu. The problem has a stellar physics context, so I don't know if fluid has be to considered as incompressible, since there are 2 different zones into star : a radiative interior zone and a convecitve zone. But I think this question is about radiative zone, if it will be able to help you , regards

Comment: -@PapaZulu. one more detail, I have taken pression gradient along $z$ like the gravity field in the question, i.e along $z$ since $\vec{g}=-g\vec{e_{z}}$. any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

We write the system of equations in the form
$$\dfrac{\partial v_{z}}{\partial t} = -\dfrac{1}{\rho_0}\dfrac{\partial \delta P}{\partial z}+\alpha g \delta T\quad(1)$$

$$\dfrac{\partial v_{x}}{\partial t} - 2\Omega_{z} v_{y}= -\dfrac{1}{\rho_0}\dfrac{\partial \delta P}{\partial x}\quad(2)$$

$$\dfrac{\partial v_{y}}{\partial t} + 2\Omega_{z} v_{x}=-\dfrac{1}{\rho_0}\dfrac{\partial \delta P}{\partial y}\quad(3)$$
For the steady flow we set
$\dfrac{\partial v_{x}}{\partial t}=\dfrac{\partial v_{y}}{\partial t}=\dfrac{\partial v_{z}}{\partial t}=0$

Integrating the first equation we find the pressure

$\delta P=\alpha\rho_0 g z\delta T(x)+f(y)$, where $f(y)$ is arbitrary function.

Assuming $\dfrac{\partial \delta P}{\partial y}=0$ (it follows from the conditions of this problem) and in this way from eq (3) we get $v_x=0$.

From the second equation we find

$v_y=\dfrac{\alpha g z}{2\Omega _z}\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial x}$

The continuity equation for incompressible flow is performed automatically on this solution because $\vec v=(0,v_y(x,z),0)$ and consequently $\nabla .\vec v=0$.

Comment: you can't say $\partial \delta P/\partial y = 0$ by integrating equation (1). For example if $\delta P = \alpha\rho_0 gz\delta T(x) + y$, then $\partial \delta P/\partial z$ is still equal to $\alpha \rho_0 g \delta T$

Comment: No, it seems to be correct for me ? why do you introduce ther term $y$ in $\delta P = \alpha\rho_0 gz\delta T(x) + y$

Comment: @PapaZulu Please read carefully 4. We consider …, under the influence of the Coriolis force and a temperature variations. No words on pressure gradient in `y` direction.

Comment: @Alex When you said "hence", it sounds like you are drawing the conclusion that $\partial \delta P/\partial y = 0$ from the integration of equation (1). This would be incorrect. But if $\delta P$ has is known to have no $y$ component a priori then yes $v_x = 0$ but one would not need to integrate equation (1) at all to find that out. I just added the $y$ as an example to show that $\delta P$ could have a $y$ component and still satisfy the equation (1). I am not saying that it is the actual function for $\delta P$

Comment: @PapaZulu  thank you, I  added a few words about continuity equation.